# What does this そうなった mean?

Tags: grammar

> 横幅が狭く、まるで両脇の建物に圧迫されて**そうなったか**のようだった

I wonder why the に disappeared? Is it something different from そうになった?

Comment: Verb + そうになったら like 言いそうになった means “I nearly ~”. そうなった means “became like that”. They are more or less unrelated

Comment: Your text has the furigana for 両脇 mixed in with the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with そうになる, but simply and literally means *became so*, where *so* should refer to the state that should be described elsewhere.

Roughly the sentence means *the road was narrow, and it looked as if it **became so** by being squeezed by the neighboring buildings*.